# How to use cudaMalloc on a pointer in a struct?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, struct, cuda

I'd like to make copying things from host to device in CUDA5.0 more convenient. So I wanted to create a function taking a host vector as argument and returning a structure like so:

```
template <typename T>
struct devArr
{
    unsigned int size;   //array size
    T *address;          //address on device
};
```

The intention is to copy data to the device anywhere in the code and then to only pass that structure to any device function that uses the data, not having to treat the array bounds separately.

The function returning the structure could for example look like that:

```
template <typename T>
struct cudaArr<T> VectorToDevice(vector<T> arr)
{
    struct devArr<T> darr;
    darr.size = arr.size();
    cudaMalloc((void**)&darr.address, arr.size()*sizeof(T));
    cudaMemcpy(darr.address,&arr[0], arr.size()*sizeof(T), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    return darr;
}
```

So all this compiles fine. But with this code the pointer in my struct doesn't point to the right address. It has to be a problem of how to handle a pointer in a struct in general. So how do I use cudaMalloc properly with a pointer in a struct?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

That's exactly how you do it. The thing which confused me and to be aware of here is that the pointer contains an address on the device memory, thus it's only valid in a device function. In host code it points to the wrong data.

Comment: For the last sentence "In host code it points to the wrong data", are you trying to use the data that the pointer points to in the host code? This will of course fail, but having a pointer in host code which holds an address to device is totally fine.

Comment: Yes, I thought, I could read out data on the device from outside a kernel function. Like that the compiler would know by itself that the address is on the device. So I was mistaking my function to be wrong, but it works fine. But the Thrust library seems to be really useful to simplify things here.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [Thrust](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/thrust/) may be useful for you, so if your use case fits that I would recommend it.

Your code uses the cuda api alright, except that the return type of `VectorToDevice` should be `devArr`.

If the following is what you want to do, you shall pass the whole `devArr` struct as value to a certain kernel function. Then you can use the device pointer.

> The intention is to copy data to the device anywhere in the code and then to only pass that structure to any device function that uses the data, not having to treat the array bounds separately.

For example, you can write a kernel function like this:

```
__global__ void add(devArr x, devArr y, devArr z) {
  if (threadIdx.x < x.size) {
    z.address[threadIdx.x] = x.address[threadIdx.x] + y.address[threadIdx.x]
  }
}
```

Then you can call it from your host code, say:

```
devArr x = VectorToDevice(x_host);
// prepare y and z similarly.
add<<<1, 100, 0>>>(x, y, z);
```

But you cannot use what x.address points to directly in host code.